# Why is it that I get texts when both wifi and cellular data are turned off?

Tags: wi-fi, sms, data

Just wondering if everything is normal on my cell phone... It's an LG and they stopped updating, but I don't remember this behavior before...

Comment: The old cellular voice and SMS services have nothing to do with data (internet) services. SMS has been available since the early days of GSM when phones didn't have internet. GSM / 3G networks still support these old services.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need cellular data to send text messages (SMS). Networks use a different method to send and receive text messages. SMS uses GSM and ISDN networks to send text messages. You are limited to 160 characters of text. The limitation reflects the speed of the network.

Answer (score 0):

There is SMS (Short Messaging Service) and MMS (Multimedia Messaging Service). SMS messages are 160 characters or less, meaning 1120 bits or less (each character is 7 bits). MMS messages (pictures or messages longer than 160 characters), however, require data. So even if you have data turned off, that will not effect SMS messaging. To turn that off you'll have to use airplane mode.